# Insert javascript code for responsive iframe in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I need to integrate some iframes created on a chart platform in my Vue.js app. The code for the responsive iframe is composed of some html code, that I put in the template and some javascript that comes between a pair of script tags.

Here is the html part:

```html
<iframe
  id="datawrapper-chart-8dfPN"
  src="//datawrapper.dwcdn.net/8dfPN/4/"
  scrolling="no"
  frameborder="0"
  allowtransparency="true"
  style="width: 0; min-width: 100% !important;" height="400"
>
</iframe>
```

and the javascript part:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  if("undefined"==typeof window.datawrapper)window.datawrapper={};
  window.datawrapper["8dfPN"]={},
  window.datawrapper["8dfPN"].embedDeltas={"100":481,"200":427,"300":400,"400":400,"500":400,"700":400,"800":400,"900":400,"1000":400},
  window.datawrapper["8dfPN"].iframe=document.getElementById("datawrapper-chart-8dfPN"),
  window.datawrapper["8dfPN"].iframe.style.height=window.datawrapper["8dfPN"].embedDeltas[Math.min(1e3,Math.max(100*Math.floor(window.datawrapper["8dfPN"].iframe.offsetWidth/100),100))]+"px",
  window.addEventListener("message",function(a){if("undefined"!=typeof a.data["datawrapper-height"])for(var b in a.data["datawrapper-height"])if("8dfPN"==b)window.datawrapper["8dfPN"].iframe.style.height=a.data["datawrapper-height"][b]+"px"});
</script>
```

I don't understand how I have to manage this code. If I put it in the template (as it has html elements) Views tells me I can't use scripts in templates. But embed the code in the  portion of my Vue file doesn't work either. I tried to get rid of the  elements. But it's not working.

Is there a way to refactor this code so I can fully use it with Vue.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the provided JavaScript, there really isn't much to it.  It's setting an initial height and then setting up an event listener to manage the iframe's height.

To start we'll bind the `height` to a data property `iframeHeight`.

```
<iframe
  ref="chartiframe"
  id="datawrapper-chart-8dfPN" 
  src="//datawrapper.dwcdn.net/8dfPN/4/"
  scrolling="no"
  frameborder="0"
  allowtransparency="true"
  style="width: 0; min-width: 100% !important;"
  :height="iframeHeight"></iframe>
```

Then

1. Create `const` variable for the `embeddedDeltas`
2. Set the initial height in the `mounted` hook.
3. Setup the `message` event listener in the `mounted` hook
4. Create a method to handle the resize
5. Remove the event listener in the `beforeDestroy` hook

ddd

```
const DELTAS = {
        "100":481,
        "200":427,
        "300":400,
        "400":400,
        "500":400,
        "700":400,
        "800":400,
        "900":400,
        "1000":400,
};

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      iframeHeight: '0px', // initial height
    };
  },
  computed: {
    // Necessary for initial iframe height
    iframeOffsetWidth() {      
      return this.$refs['chartiframe'].offsetWidth;
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    // set initial iframe height
    this.iframeHeight = `{DELTAS[Math.min(1e3,Math.max(100*Math.floor(this.iframeOffsetWidth/100),100))]}px`;
    // setup event listener
    window.addEventListener('message', this.handleIframeResize);
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    // destroy event listener
    window.removeEventListener('message', this.handleIframeResize);
  },
  methods: {
    handleIframeResize(e) {
      for(var b in e.data['datawrapper-height']) {
        if ('8dfPN' === b) {
          this.iframeHeight = `${e.data['datawrapper-height'][b]}px`;
        }
      }
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Too good! Thanks for your help. I added the code in my vue file and yes, no more chocking. Now I have to go a bit further. The iframes are displayed selectively with a select form, each option is linked to a condition in each div with iframe. When the option is selected in the menu by the user, the div (and only this one) shows. As I have a dozen iframes, I need to find a way to refactor and replace the iframe Id by a variable in the differents parts (computed, mount, methods, ...). Do you have an idea how I could do this?

Comment: @Plouf Use an array of objects to track the iframes.  Place your urls, an identifier, and the iframeHeight in each object.  The select can track the index of which to show and apply the iframeHeight to. Then use a `v-for` to loop over the array and generate your html.

Comment: I will try this, thks. Looks that I have a complete solution in sight with your help, now!